# TCP send special ASCII characters

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I want to send command to the device through TCP/IP. but the sent characters were decoded in wrong and then the device can not decode them.

I have tried to use `encode('utf-8')` or `b''` to deal with them but unsuccessful.

```
TCP_IP = '10.38.94.133' 
port = 2049
cc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cc.connect((TCP_IP, port))

sendstr = '11004¶1¶1\r'.encode('utf-8')

cc.sendall(sendstr) 

data = cc.recv(1024)
print()
```

the error is :

```
b'READ failed: tag 11004\xc2\xb61\xc2\xb61\r\n'
```

which shows the command was encoded in wrong way. so the device can not understand it. 
the special char is a Separator = "¶" (ASCII 182) . 
anyone can explain what's wrong in the code?
thanks in advance!

Comment: ASCII only defines a 7-bit character set, and it doesn't include the pilcrow.  "ASCII 182" implies you have a specific character set in mind, so you should encode to that rather than `utf-8`.

Comment: You probably want `'11004¶1¶1\r'.encode('cp1252')`.

Comment: So, what does the device's documentation or manufacturer say about character encodings? There is no text but encoded text.

Comment: My guess that you just need to use `cc.sendall(b'11004\xb61\xb61\r')`, i.e. a byte sequence where `\xb6` is the byte 182 (which is not ASCII). No encoding should be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. all the methods you proposed work well. I also tried to `b"11004%c1%c%d\r" % (182, 182, 1)` which also works. Thanks a lot:)